# Nx, Vite, React library does not apply Scss styles in the build

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, vite, nx-monorepo

I am new to the `Nx` monorepo, and I have built a couple of commonly used components in `React` to be used in a library called web, with styling handled by `SCSS`. When I use the library in the apps within the monorepo, it works perfectly. However, when I create a package and use it externally, none of the `SCSS` styles are being applied to the library.
Except for the styling other things seems to be working in the package.

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "@example/web",
  "version": "1.1.3",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "./index.js",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./index.mjs",
      "require": "./index.js"
    }
  },
  "repository": {
    "directory": "libs/web",
    "type": "git",
    "url": "...."
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
  }
}
```

> project.json

```
{
  "name": "web",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "libs/web/src",
  "projectType": "library",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "lint": {
      /////////
    },
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/vite:build",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/libs/web"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "mode": "development"
        },
        "production": {
          "mode": "production"
        }
      }
    },
    "test": {
      ////////////
    }
  }
}
```

> vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/web',
  plugins: [
    dts({
      entryRoot: 'src',
      tsConfigFilePath: joinPathFragments(__dirname, 'tsconfig.lib.json'),
      skipDiagnostics: true,
    }),
    react(),
    viteTsConfigPaths({
      root: '../../',
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: 'src/index.ts',
      name: 'web',
      fileName: 'index',
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react/jsx-runtime']
    },
  },
});
```

It seems like the styles are bundled with the output file index.js based on the documentation. However, despite observing a style.css file being generated with all the styles included, it appears that, even when added manually to the project, the styles are not being applied properly.

> build dir

[image: build dir]

If there were a plugin available to inject SCSS styles into the output index.js file, it would be an ideal solution. Alternatively, any other viable solution for this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: A temp solution would be `cssCodeSplit: true` to the `vite.config.ts` to get a working css file and importing it in the project